# Normality of data used to estimate significance of ARIMA parameters?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, arima, normality-assumption, state-space-models

Does significance testing (p-value, 95% prediction interval of a forecast, etc.) of an ARIMA model require time series data to be normally distributed? As in, according to the tests used to assess normality before linear regression (histogram, qqplot, etc.)?

If not, why?

Similarly, what about state-space models, such as ETS?

Comment: The conditional distribution is definitely important: if you forecast nonnegative or intermittent count data, ARIMA or ETS prediction intervals will be nonsensically negative and noninteger. But that is not what you are asking. PIs are usually calculated based on a normality assumption on innovations, but there are few people working on ARIMA/ETS with nonnormal innovations. For p-values on (P)ACF or parameter estimates, I suspect that the CLT kicks in for "reasonable" innovation distributions.

Comment: Thanks! What about for the p-values of the parameter estimates themselves?

Comment: See my comment: I would assume that a CLT (not "the" CLT, because time series observations are of course not independent) kicks in and makes parameter estimates asymptotically normal. [This may be helpful, but it's just my first search result.](https://www.quora.com/Do-time-series-data-obey-the-central-limit-theorem)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is very informative! Can you elaborate or supply a link to clarify what you mean by innovation distribution?

Comment: The "innovation" is one possible term for the random disturbances. If $y_t = \phi_1y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, then we have an AR(1) process, and the $\epsilon_t$ are the *innovations* (which are usually assumed to be white noise, [and often implicitly to be *Gaussian* white noise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/609249/1352)).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much!